# Wget fails to download PNG files from Blogger

Tags: wget

I am trying to mirror a blogger site so that I can have an exact copy of it
on my filesystem to view. I have tried issuing the following command on Linux:

```
wget -r -k -x -e robots=off --wait 1 http://your.site.here.blogspot.com/
```

I have even tried using the -D flag to list a comma-separated list of domanins
to follow (would prefer to just follow any domain though without having to
specify all of them). I have even tried changing the .com part of the URL
to the top-level domain for my country (.it) (without which for some reason
I don't understand and would like to know, wget retrieves only index.html
and no other page, perhaps someone here can explain why).

So, even when I do a

```
wget -r -k -x -e robots=off --wait 1 http://your.site.here.blogspot.it/
```

several HTML and also the favicon.ico are downloaded but none of the .png
images from blogger are downloaded. Why is this so and how can I get wget
to work properly. I've read the wget man page but had no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the `.png` images are hosted on `http://your.site.here.blogspot.it/`? Images uploaded to the Blogger service seem to be served from `<number>.bp.blogspot.com` instead, which would explain why `wget` won't fetch them.

Comment: Have you considered a User Agent change? some sites prevent images/pages from being parsed by different robots/tools.

Answer (score 4):

As `jayhendren` suggested, I had tried listing the domain bp.blogspot.com on the list following the -D flag. However what I forgot to do is add the -H flag. Why wget requires the extra -H flag to be added separately from the list of domains to follow with the -D flag is unclear to me, but it works. Here is the command I ultimately specified to mirror the Blogger site including the images served from the external domain:

```
wget --domains=blogspot.it,bp.blogspot.com -H --mirror -e robots=off \
  --wait 0.5 --convert-links http://yoursitehere.blogspot.it/
```

Note: this works from Italy. Convert .it to .com or to whatever other top-level domain if you want this to work from your location.

Regards.

Comment: Awesome, I've been pulling my hair out trying to archive a blog's images as well as its pages, but I've run into so many dead ends. The `--domains` flag is exactly the ticket; it does what you expect and the `-k` flag AKA `--convert-links` is also fantastic. There's a [great article here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150801234942/http://nerds-central.blogspot.com:80/2008/05/how-to-automate-backup-of-blogspot-blog.html) which offers even more options for archiving a Blogger site, whose author owns a Blogger site himself.

Answer (score 0):

Without error output of wget I can't tell what's the exact problem you have. But generally when downloading (or mirroring a website) with wget, I'll use the -mirror option like this:

```
wget --mirror -p --adjust-extension --wait 1 http://your.site.here.blogspot.it/
```

Comment: Well, from the man page the -p option takes a parameter so this can't be right. Also, -e robots=off is required since the site I am mirroring would otherwise disallow mirroring through the robots.txt file. The -wait 1 option is so the server does not get overloaded. However the image files do not get downloaded. Try this on any blogspot.com site and see for yourself. Where am I going wrong?